# Max of 99percentile in a window of list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy

I have a list of lists(2000x1000), but as example consider this one(10x3):

```
l = [[8, 7, 6], [5, 3, 1], [4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 1], [3, 5, 7], [8, 2, 5], [1, 9, 2], [8, 7, 6], [9, 9, 9], [4, 5, 9]]
```

In this example, every list corresponds to 3 measurements of each instant:

`t0` -> [8,7,6]

`t1` -> [5,3,1]
and so on.

I would like to compare the measurements with a window of 4 instants for position and take the max value which is in the 99 percentile of the peak to peak value.

### EXAMPLE

Lets consider the first window:

```
[8, 7, 6], [5, 3, 1], [4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 1] :
[8,5,4,1] -> peak to peak: 8-1=7
[7,3,5,5] -> ptp=4
[6,1,9,1] -> ptp=8
```

with these 3 values `[7,4,8]` I want to take the max in the 99percentile, in this case `7`

For the second window:

```
[5, 3, 1], [4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 1], [3, 5, 7]:
[5,4,1,3] -> ptp=4
[3,5,5,5] -> ptp=2
[1,9,1,7] -> ptp=8
```

max in 99percentile -> `4`
After I do that for all the windows of size 4, I want to make a list with these values.

My code is this the following one, but it is slow. Is there a fast way to implement this?

### NOTE: I cannot use pandas, and Numpy version should be <=1.6

```
num_meas = 4
m = []
for index, i in enumerate(l):
    if index < len(l) - num_meas + 1:
        p = []
        for j in range(len(i)):
            t = []
            for k in range(num_meas):
                t.append(l[index + k][j])
            t = [x for x in t if ~np.isnan(x)]
            try:
                a = np.ptp(t)
            except ValueError:
                a = 0
            p.append(a)
        perce = np.percentile(p, 99)
        p = max([el for el in p if el < perce])
        m.append(p)
print m
```

The output:

```
[7, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7]
```

Comment: 2000x1000, the example is 10x3

Comment: Does that mean you can use numpy>1.6 ?

Comment: No, that has to be 1.6 or previous to it

Comment: There is a little mistake in a peak to peak example, [7,3,5,9] -> ptp=6 should be [7,3,5,5] -> ptp=4

Comment: Thanks, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the following code works with NumPy 1.6:

```
import numpy as np

l = [[8, 7, 6], [5, 3, 1], [4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 1], [3, 5, 7], [8, 2, 5],
     [1, 9, 2], [8, 7, 6], [9, 9, 9], [4, 5, 9]]

l = np.array(l)

# range matrix
mat_ptp = np.zeros((l.shape[0]-3, l.shape[1]))

for i in range(l.shape[0]-3):
    l[i:i+4].ptp(axis=0, out=mat_ptp[i])

percentiles = np.percentile(mat_ptp, 99, axis=1)
greater_pos = np.greater_equal(mat_ptp, percentiles.reshape(-1, 1))
mat_ptp[greater_pos] = -np.inf

result = np.max(mat_ptp, axis=1)
```

For enhancing performance, you can try to vetorize your operations as much as possible using numpy. It could be much faster than using `for` loops and the `append` function.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't notice that you wanted the selected elements strictly less than the percentile. Here is the correct version.

**BENCHMARK**

Just to validate the question about performance, here is the result with:

```
l = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(200, 100))
```

run 100 times with `timeit`:

```
OP code: 0.5197743272900698 ms in average
Code above: 0.0021439407201251015 in average
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the approach seems faster and easier, but it gives a wrong output. For the example i posted, it gives: `[7 4 7 7 7 7]`

Comment: @Joe Sorry, I didn't notice that you wanted the selected elements strictly less than the percentile. I just edited my answer.

Comment: If i have `nan`, and i want to ignore them in the percentile and max, what should i do?

Comment: @Joe Well, this really depends on what you want to do with `NaNs`. In most cases I will eliminate them during preprocessing because it will be chaotic to deal with them all the time during operations. I will simply do `l[np.isnan(l)] = a_value`. But how to choose `a_value` is problem-specific. In your case, `np.ptp` does not ignores `NaN`. So if you are not going to take `NaN` into account when calculating percentiles, you can just leave it and use `np.nanmax` in the end. P.S. With `Numpy>=1.9` you can use `np.nanpercentile` as well. So I recommend that you move on to latest numpy versions.